# Blazor - getting System.BadImageFormatException the second time i do hot reload

Tags: blazor, badimageformatexception

i have a website in blazor server that throws System.BadImageFormatException the second time i do hot reload

the project is in net8, upgraded from net7 only in project file.
this website is a Side-by-side incremental upgrade from net 4.5 using the yarp proxy.

the two project are both set to start on debug.

I don't know exactly when it begin but now when I edit some blazor component and then click hot reload the first time works well but if i made a second change and then re-click hot reload i get the error System.BadImageFormatException on the page i made change but i can navigate the other pages without problems.

To exclude problems on the computer in use I created a new clean blazor project and follow the two edit steps and everything works fine.

Comment: Have you checked out the [documentation on BadImageFormatException by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-8.0#remarks)? There are many reasons this can happen listed there. You just have to check them.

Comment: @Mushroomator the first time i do hot reload works fine. the error is systematic, it occurs even if I insert simple text or a tag in the html. it always happens the second time I change something and click hot reload

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But that doesn't answer my question. You need to check all the reasons provided by Microsoft. You have provided far too little details to do remote debugging. For this problem it's not unlikely that you cannot provide enough information at all on this page, since it more or less involves checking your whole solution, its projects and their dependencies as well as build/ compile options etc.. So please checkout the linked resource.

Comment: @Mushroomator based on the link you posted I tried to configure all the projects in my solution in x86. but for some reason the old project (net 4.5) didn't apply the x86 configuration.
therefore I came to the decision to divide the application into two solutions. now I can work without problems on the blazor project and use the hot reload functionality. thanks for the link which, based on the suggested tests, highlighted the possible problem, although I would have preferred to have everything in a single solution